# How to Dump Protected libil2cpp.so and Metadata from Application on Android without Root

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, dump, lib, smali

I'm trying to reverse-engineer the app on Android. Unfortunately, the lib named libil2cpp.so and metadata is protected. When I try to dump using libil2cpp dumper online or any tools, the process fails as you can see in this  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCE2O.jpg)

I want to dump it without root using an Android phone. Please respect my post. Thank you